# Get some data from a table in my database - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an association of my model Banner with Images, I need to bring all the images but only the field file, in file I have a hash in which I just want to get the url

I have this code:

```
Banner.find_by(event_id: @event.id).to_json(:include => [{:images => {:only => [:file]}}])
```

but this gets me this:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "created_at": "2019-04-24T14:59:08.000-05:00",
  "updated_at": "2019-04-24T14:59:08.000-05:00",
  "event_id": 3,
  "name": "ccccccccccccccccccccccssssss",
  "images": [
    {
      "file": {
        "url": "/uploads/image/file/300aecf6-b3c7-4b15-94a1-45c530efc4c4.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want something like this:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "created_at": "2019-04-24T14:59:08.000-05:00",
  "updated_at": "2019-04-24T14:59:08.000-05:00",
  "event_id": 3,
  "name": "ccccccccccccccccccccccssssss",
  "images": [
    "/uploads/image/file/300aecf6-b3c7-4b15-94a1-45c530efc4c4.png"
  ]
}
```

How could I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best to break things up into smaller pieces...

```rb
# create the query to get all the objects to prevent n+1 queries
banners = Banner.includes(images: :file)

# get the banner you want to serialize
banner = banners.find_by(event_id: @event.id)

# get all the urls for the images as an array
image_urls = banner.images.collect {|i| i.file.url }

# create the json object
json = banner.to_json.merge(images: image_urls)
```